# Is EXDATE not included in rrule for Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, rrule, fullcalendar-4

I have a recurring calendar event that happens on the 4th Friday of every month and I want to exclude 1 Friday event. I've tried `EXDATE` but I'm getting an error

> Failure passing JSON

Without `EXDATE` the rrule works fine.

Here are the details that I'm using in Full Calendar to produce the event

```
{
    start: "2019-07-06T09:00:00+10:00",
    end: "2019-07-06T15:00:00+10:00",
    rrule: "FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20190607T090000;EXDATE=20190705T090000;INTERVAL=4;BYDAY=FR",
    title: "Weed Spraying",
    description: "June, Harry, Pat, George, Valda, Helen, Karen, Ken",
    color: "red",
    url: "./?action=detail_view&id=22",
    duration: "06:00"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add exceptions. You just need to format the RRule string correct:

```
DTSTART:20190610T103000\nRRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20190801\nEXDATE:20190618T103000Z\nEXDATE:20190619T103000
```

Watch this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/koz06m2op3) for a demo

Comment: Full Calendar also accepts an object instead of a string. Can you provide an example of how we would implement it in that form with multiple dates?

Comment: Beware, there's currently a bug in fullcalendar/rrule connector that causes multiple EXDATEs to not work properly if you supply the dates in UTC format (trailing Z). See https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5726

Answer (score 4):

OK I worked it out, @Arnaud is right, RRULE, EXDATE and DTSTART are properties not parameters of rrule, BUT they do go in the rrule property for FullCalendar with a \n newline, they also require a : NOT =. Example

```
rrule: 'DTSTART:20190308T120000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20220330\nEXDATE:20190614T120000Z\nEXDATE:20190628T120000Z'
```

Notice how there are 2 EXDATE properties, for each date you want to exclude, you need to put an EXDATE.
I spent 3 days trying to get this to work, hopefully this will help save someone else time.

Comment: I'm going to assume this has just saved me 3 days. I'm in great debt to you.

Comment: Beware, there's currently a bug in fullcalendar/rrule connector that causes multiple EXDATEs to not work properly if you supply the dates in UTC format (trailing Z). See https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5726

Comment: Man, you saved me quite some time and nerves!

Comment: @jiroch adding the 'Z' char for RRule datetimes now works in v5.4.0 https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5726

Comment: What do you mean `for each date you want to exclude`? So you're saying that if I want to exclude 05/03/2021 then that date has to be there twice? If so, in your example I only see one per date: `20190614T120000Z` and `20190628T120000Z`, which don't match.

Answer (score 2):

This format can also be used for multiple EXDATE:

```
rrule: "DTSTART:20201114T000000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY\nEXDATE:20201121T000000Z,20201128T000000Z"
```

This string was formatted using `rruleSet.exdate(new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 5, 1, 10, 30)))` from rrule.js library to add multiple EXDATE in the rrule object then using the method `.toString()`

Also, note that adding the 'Z' char for RRule datetimes now works in v5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Do not know much about this particular JSON format but the EXDATE is a property, not a parameter of RRULE.
Please try

```
rrule: "FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20190607T090000;INTERVAL=4;BYDAY=FR\nEXDATE=20190705T090000"
```

Comment: I can't see how this is any better than the OP's code, or why it would be valid. I highly doubt that the RRULE format has newline (`\n`) characters as an accepted separator. All you've done is replace `;` with `\n` which I doubt is valid. I don't know the format that well, but it doesn't look meaningful. Can you explain the difference between a "property" and a "parameter" in RRULE, exactly?

Comment: OK it looks like it is more of an rrule.js issue than a fullcalendar issue. The rrule plugin being used throws an error Unknown RRULE property 'EXDATE'. It also does this on the rrule demo page http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/ if you try entering FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20190607T090000;EXDATE=20190705T090000;INTERVAL=4;BYDAY=FR as a text string, you get the same error.

Comment: @ADyson Both RRULE and EXDATE are defined as properties by RFC5545. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3 and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.1 for their respective definitions as well as https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.2 to help you understand what this is all about. In the original post, the EXDATE is made a parameter of RRULE instead of a property in its own right.
Then if you look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin you will see that multiple properties can be specified in the rrule, separated by \n

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like only the DTSTART property can be specified in rrule and no recurrence related properties (EXDATE or RDATE).

Comment: Looking at the docs on https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule, I'm assuming that I have to use the RRuleSet Constructor ie. RRuleSet.prototype.exdate(dt) to set each EXDATE, but I have no idea where to do that in the fullCalendar code

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version 5.4.0 the following code will work:

DTSTART:20201101T040000Z
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU
EXDATE:20201110T040000Z,20201124T040000Z

FullCalendar now supports multiple exdate

I used the RRule and RRuleSet to produce the rrule string:
*NOTE: You will have to be careful with daylight savings. That's why I had to adjust a couple of times. Do not focus on my specific date object. This is just an example of the solution to support multiple exdates using RRuleSet and RRule.

```
const rruleSet = new RRuleSet();
    rruleSet.rrule(new RRule({
      freq: Frequency.WEEKLY,
      interval: 1,
      byweekday: [RRule.TU],
      dtstart: new Date(2020, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    }));
    rruleSet.exdate(new Date(2020, 10, 9, 23, 0, 0, 0));
    rruleSet.exdate(new Date(2020, 10, 23, 23, 0, 0, 0));
    console.log(rruleSet.toString());
```

Here is the issue number:
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5726

Comment: Are you sure about this? When i try parse a RRULE with an EXDATE it says EXDATE is an invalid property.

Comment: When i save the string and try have fullcalendar use that string at a later stage i get the following: Unsupported RFC prop EXDATE in EXDATE:20201109T210000Z,20201123T210000Z. Fullcalendar cannot parse these EXDATES at a later stage. See https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule/issues/335  and https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4549

Comment: Use RRuleSet not RRule and make sure you are using full calendar version 5.4.0

Comment: i have a whole bunch of JSON event data with the EXDATE in it. When i send this to fullcalendar it throws an error saying EXDATE is invalid. How are you getting RRuleSet into Fullcalendar 5.4.0?

Comment: @PiotrStulinski Post a sample of your RRULE and I'll have a look

Comment: My issue was as follows - time portion of EXDATE was different which does not work, secondly the EXDATE must be on a newline. Thanks for the responses.